# PHP - Does mysql_fetch_assoc return a two dimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

when

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users';
```

and there are multiple columns/rows, does `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`
return a two-dimensional array?

Can I draw each row by simply saying: `array_pop(mysql_fetch_assoc($r))`

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*mysql_fetch_assoc* returns an *associative array* (an array with the selected column names as keys), one row at a time until there are no more rows in the result of the query. Call it in a loop to work with a row at a time:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["username"];
    echo $row["email"];
}
```

(Assuming username and email are columns in the users table).

Answer (score 4):

No, it returns a single row.

Calling it again will return the next row, until there are no more rows.

You can build a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
    $rows[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 2):

array_pop will unset the first value of the array and return it, so in your case your first table field would be unset.